# Grouping a list of dictionaries by the same value in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries:

```
players= [
   { "name": 'matt', 'school': 'WSU', 'homestate': 'CT', 'position': 'RB' },
   { "name": 'jack', 'school': 'ASU', 'homestate': 'AL', 'position': 'QB' },
   { "name": 'john', 'school': 'WSU', 'homestate': 'MD', 'position': 'LB' },
   { "name": 'kevin', 'school': 'ALU', 'homestate': 'PA', 'position': 'LB' },
   { "name": 'brady', 'school': 'UM', 'homestate': 'CA', 'position': 'QB' },
]
```

How do I group them into groups by matching their matching dictionary values, such that it spews out:

> Matching Value 1:
>
> > name: [matt, john, kevin],
> >
> > school: [WSU, WSU, ALU],
> >
> > homestate: [CT, MD, PA]
> >
> > position: [RB, LB, LB]
>
> Matching Value 2:
>
> > name: [jack, brady],
> >
> > school: [ASU, UM],
> >
> > homestate: [AL, CA]
> >
> > position: [QB, QB]

Notice that the matching values are arbitrary; that is, it can be found anywhere. Maybe its in `school` or in `position`, or maybe in both.

I tried grouping them by doing:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result_dictionary = {}

for i in players:
    for key, value in i.items():
        result_dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Which gives out:

```
{'name': ['matt', 'jack', 'john', 'kevin', 'brady'], 
 'school': ['WSU', 'ASU', 'WSU', 'ALU', 'UM'], 
 'homestate': ['CT', 'AL', 'MD', 'PA', 'CA'], 
 'position': ['RB', 'QB', 'LB', 'QB', 'QB']}
```

But I'm stuck on how do I further manipulate the output to match the required output I stated above, and I am sure there are better, simpler approach in doing it.

Comment: if you have an option then I would suggest you use pandas. You can easily group

Comment: "The matching values is arbitrary; that is, it can be found anywhere. Maybe its in school or in position, or maybe in both." This is not clear. Can you give examples that clarify?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the rules are here (what if Matt and John went to the same school, but Matt and Jack played the same position? Do you have a Matt&John group and a Matt&Jack group? Or collapse them into one group even though John&Jack have nothing in common? Or pick one arbitrarily to put Matt with? Or pick non-arbitrarily (trying to maximize or minimize number of groups, maybe)? Or…?

Comment: And if the answer to that question means it's not supposed to put the players into some kind of equivalence class-style partition: What if Matt and John went to the same school and also played the same position? Is there one Matt&John group, or two, or is either acceptable?

Comment: Anyway, a general way to start at this: for each property, first do `sorted(players, key=itemgetter(propname))`, then do `groupby` on the same key. So for the school, you have a group of all the WSU players, a group of all the ASU players, etc. Then from the position, you get a group of all QBs, a group of all RBs, etc. If you need to do any merging or filtering, you can do that after the fact. Depending on what that merging or filtering is, it may be less efficient to build up more than you need just to merge, but only by a constant factor, and it's a lot simpler to think about.

Comment: Also, a hint for using groupby: it returns an iterator with subiterators, which is a hard things to debug. Try `grouped = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in grouped]` to make a non-lazy version for print-debugging or pdb-debugging (and then go back to using the lazy version once it works).

Comment: @abarnert I edited the "matching value" result to clarify the confusion

Comment: The edited version doesn't answer my questions. You just picked another example that happens to partition things no matter which variant of the rules applies, so I still can't guess which variant you want.

Comment: Take your existing example, but change Matt to a QB. What are the groups, and why?

Comment: @abarnert So we see that the general thumb-rule is that when we found more than 1 similar value, we merge it. No matter where we find them, whether in school, position, etc. For example player1 and player2 who are QB's went to the same school, we merge them. Then when player3 comes in who went to a DIFFERENT school but plays as a QB, we also merge them together, as we found similar value in three of them

Comment: @YukaLangbuana That still doesn't answer the question. If Matt was a QB instead of an RB, what would the groups be?

Comment: @abarnert Matt would still be grouped with the same WSU students since Matt and John went to the same school.

Comment: @YukaLangbuana So why wouldn't Matt be grouped with the other QBs instead of or in addition to being grouped with the other WSU students?

Comment: @abarnert That is a good question and certainly need adressing. But that's how the prompt goes. (This is my last year coding challenge question)

Comment: Then honestly, the right answer to the challenge would have been to explain that it's an ambiguous problem and has no correct solution as written. But that no longer matters. If you want to solve this, you get to pick your own set of rules that actually cover the cases unambiguously, and then you can implement those rules. I explained how to get started by using `groupby(sorted(…))` above.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `collections.defaultdict` that you already imported:

```
In [21]: from collections import defaultdict
    ...: result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    ...: for d in players:
    ...:     for k,v in d.items():
    ...:         result[d['school']][k].append(v)
    ...:

In [22]: result
Out[22]:
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'ASU': defaultdict(list,
                         {'homestate': ['AL'],
                          'name': ['jack'],
                          'position': ['QB'],
                          'school': ['ASU']}),
             'WSU': defaultdict(list,
                         {'homestate': ['CT', 'MD'],
                          'name': ['matt', 'john'],
                          'position': ['RB', 'LB'],
                          'school': ['WSU', 'WSU']})})
```

Comment: What if, let's say, the matching value was arbitrary; Maybe it can be found in 'homestate' or 'school'. How do you handle that?

Comment: @YukaLangbuana access the appropriate value? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: My mistake, I edited the question to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the most common occurring header value and use the latter value as a focal point for further grouping:

```
import itertools
players= [
  { "name": 'matt', 'school': 'WSU', 'homestate': 'CT', 'position': 'RB' },
  { "name": 'jack', 'school': 'ASU', 'homestate': 'AL', 'position': 'QB' },
  { "name": 'john', 'school': 'WSU', 'homestate': 'MD', 'position': 'LB' },
  { "name": 'kevin', 'school': 'ALU', 'homestate': 'PA', 'position': 'S' },
  { "name": 'brady', 'school': 'UM', 'homestate': 'CA', 'position': 'QB' },
]
headers = ['name', 'school', 'homestate', 'position'] 
final_header = [[a, max(b, key=lambda x:b.count(x))] for a, b in zip(headers, zip(*[[i[b] for b in headers] for i in players])) if len(set(b)) < len(b)]
d = [[list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(filter(lambda x:x[i] == c, players), key=lambda x:x[i])][0] for i, c in final_header]
last_results = {'pattern {}'.format(i):{d[0][0]:[j[-1] for j in d] for c, d in zip(headers, zip(*map(dict.items, h)))} for i, h in enumerate(d, start=1)}
```

Output:

```
{'pattern 2': 
  {'homestate': ['AL', 'CA'], 
  'school': ['ASU', 'UM'], 
  'name': ['jack', 'brady'], 
  'position': ['QB', 'QB']}, 

'pattern 1': 
    {'homestate': ['CT', 'MD'], 
    'school': ['WSU', 'WSU'], 
    'name': ['matt', 'john'], 
    'position': ['RB', 'LB']}
}
```